# Creating Max Possible Groups

Tags: php, grouping, distribution

I think there is a logical / mathematical solution to this problem and I am pretty sure someone here knows the answer. :)

This is being written in PHP.

Lets say I have 3 apples, 3 bananas, and 3 oranges.

I need to be able to create the maximum amount of "Fruit Baskets possible" with categories / requirements of:

---

Category A = Any Fruit / 3 Required

Category B = Bananas or Oranges / 2 Required

Category C = Oranges / 1 Required

Category D = Apples or Bananas / 2 Required

---

What are the maximum number of baskets I can make? I need to know how to get the solution, not necessarily what the solution is. I also would like to know what this is called if anyone knows.

Additionally, these numbers can grow into the thousands, so I need to be able to do this without destroying the computer.

Comment: Do you need your basket combinations to be mutually exclusive or you count everytime from the start of the inventory?

Comment: If you always have one basket per group, you need n baskets (where n is the number of groups).  If you can have _combinations_ of baskets (such as apparently for B and D), you end up with n! baskets - your computer will die some time in the double-digits, I believe.

Comment: This is not homework, I'm actually working on a project. I would like the basket combinations, but it is not necessary, as I know the combinations could hog a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called "combinations"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you then need to setup and array of conditions, an array of "inventory" and an array of results.

Your inventory should contain all the "fruits" you need with the amount available as a value:

```
$inventory = array(
    'oranges' => 2800,
    'apples' => 1600,
    'bananas' => 3000,
)
```

You will then need to setup the conditions to building each basket type. Organizing these conditions will require sub arrays probably. Here's an example:

```
$conditions = array(
    'basketa' => array(
        'alloweditems' => array('oranges', 'apple'),
        'requireditems' => 2
    ),
    'basketb' => array(
        'alloweditems' => array('bananas', 'apple'),
        'requireditems' => 2
    ),
)
```

The last step will be to loop your baskets checking the Allowed Items and loading the COUNT of each available items. Combine them to get a total of fruits available and simply divide the total by the number of required fruits. To get a rounded number use "FLOAT($number)" to get the least amount of possible baskets...

Comment: I believe danielrsmith is right here about this being a combination. If I just loop through, it's only finding one possible combination and that combination might not even fulfill the requirement. Furthermore, what X-Zero said, also seems correct, as the number of combinations are going to possibly be huge, potentially killing the computer.

Comment: You asked for 2 items in bananas and apples, never said you needed to have exactly 1 apple and 1 banana. Neither did you say you wanted your baskets to be mutually exclusives which at this rate makes it impossible to guess...

Comment: This has nothing to do with code or with programming really.  It is a simple math problem which can be represented as a equation of combinations.  A basket is represented as a combination with certain requirements.